# Is there a program that will tell when I click on anything where the link is currently mapped to, or the command being run for that specific action?

Tags: windows, application-launch

I am looking for something that will tell me what command is being run for an action to happen in Windows 10/11.

---

For example,

I have Malwarebytes running in my system tray:

[image]

When I right-click, I get multiple options and I am curious to know that when I click on "Check for Updates" for example, what exact command is being run to make that happen.

[image]

Is there something out there that is close to having a feature like this?

NOTE: I am not particular curious in making this work only work for Malwarebytes, I am just using this as an example. Ideally the solution would work for anything I click on.

Comment: There is NO general solution for this. Launching a function/link from a menu like that can be implemented in a 1000 different ways. Every piece of software does it differently. Unless you have access to the source-code of the program in question there is no way to determine what happens "behind the screens". (At least for the average user. A knowledgeable  programmer could probably figure things out with debugging tools given enough time and effort.)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to achieve what you are after I'm afraid.

If there is a specific function you want command control over it would be best to ask for it specifically, and in as much detail as possible as part of your question, including anything you have tried so far up to this point.

The answer sadly is that this cannot be done, due to the limitless ways a program can call its own internal functions with respect to the language / coding platform it was written in and there are many, to name the main ones:

Java, Python, C, Ruby, JavaScript, C#, PHP, Objective-C, SQL, etc...

In addition to this, the many scripts, services and dll files a program may call as part of it's purpose. A DLL contains functions, classes, variables, UIs and resources - as you can see the list goes on and on.

To put it simply, it's not a simple command that is triggered when you interact with software that is above the basic level programming. Most of the time there is a lot going on in the background.